# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation when using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was trying to upload an image to PHP using jQuery AJAX, but I get an 'Illegal invocation' error in the console, so I can't.

Can anyone tell me why? I was trying to find a solution but can't find any.

```js
$('#createUsers').click(function() {
  var img = $('#userimgs').prop('files')[0];
  var code = $('#userCode').val();
  var lname = $('#userLname').val();
  var fname = $('#userFname').val();
  var mname = $('#userMname').val();
  var birth = $('#userbirth').val();
  var email = $('#usermail').val();
  var address = $('#userAddress').val();
  var uname = $('#userUname').val();
  var pass = $('#userPass').val();
  var confirm = $('#userConfirm').val();
  var position = $('#user_position').val();
  var validCode = $.isNumeric(code);

  var forms = new FormData();
  forms.append("file", img);
  forms.append("code", code);
  forms.append("lname", lname);
  forms.append("fname", fname);
  forms.append("mname", mname);
  forms.append("birth", birth);
  forms.append("email", email);
  forms.append("address", address);
  forms.append("uname", uname);
  forms.append("pass", pass);
  forms.append("position", position);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'insertUser.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: forms,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'success') {
        Toast.show('User Added Succesfully', 'success');
        $('#userimgs').prop('files')[0];
        $('#userCode').val('');
        $('#userLname').val('');
        $('#userFname').val('');
        $('#userMname').val('');
        $('#userbirth').val('');
        $('#usermail').val('');
        $('#userAddress').val('');
        $('#userUname').val('');
        $('#userPass').val('');
        $('#userConfirm').val('');
        $('#user_position').val('');

        $('.userstbl-content').fadeIn(400).show();
        $('.users-authentication, .create-auth-user').hide();
      } else if (data == 'invalid') {
        Toast.show('User failed to add', 'error');
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't appear to throw that error. As a debugging tip, the error in the console should give you the filename and line number which points directly to the source of the error, or a callstack. Check that to find the exact source of the problem.

Comment: Also note that you can halve the amount of code you've got there by putting all the `input` elements in a `form` and using just `var forms = new FormData(yourFormElementReferenceHere);`, and then putting a common class on those inputs to just do `$('.form-element').val('')` to clear them in a single line of code. More info on the FormData constructor at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)